# Perisistent EC2 IP association even after instance stop/start

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I have a single EC2 instance and a single Elastic IP. After the instance is stoped and then re-started, the association between the instance and the IP is lost and I have to manually re-associate.

Is there a way either through the AWS Management Console or programatically from within the instance to do the re-association?

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly certain that the association stayed, but if it doesn't:

- Download the EC2 command line API tools (google how to do this for your OS)
- Set up a simple script to re-associate itself on startup.

Comment: I am certain that, at least in my case, the IP does not remain associated after a stop/start cycle. I will try what you suggest with the API tools and comment later.

Comment: The IP doesn't remain associated after a stop. They automatically deassociate it, and bill you $0.01 per hour you hold an unassociated IP.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/316403/what-is-the-best-practise-for-assigning-an-ec2-eip-after-starting-an-instance  has an example script.